# How do I create an object and paint it while it moves?

Tags: c#, winforms, draw, paint

I want to create a circle object, put it on the screen with a velocity, and have it bounce around within the borders. I can setup the circle class just fine, but how do I paint the object (and multiple ones later, say click and you get more circle objects) and show its movement?

Comment: This is kind of a broad question with lots of specific sub topics. You might want to split your question up into seperate more focused questions.

Comment: Are you using WinForms, APS, WPF or Silverlight?

Comment: If there is an option you can use WPF then do it. It's not a problem there, but in WinForms you'll have to do everything manually. Read this: http://www.leadtools.com/Help/LEADTOOLS/v15/DH/Wpf/TO/Leadtools.Wpf.Topics~Leadtools.Wpf.Topics.DifferencesBetweenGDIANDWPF.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drawing can be accomplished in at least 3 different ways in .NET (WFA, WPF, and XNA frameworks). For this answer I will assume you're using the simplest: a WinForms app.

Drawing/painting custom shapes in .NET is accomplished using the `Graphics` class. All form controls have a `CreateGraphics()` method, which gives you a reference to a "box" on the screen with the size and location of the control on which you called the method. Using that `Graphics` instance, you can call various Draw methods (like `DrawCircle()`) to put shapes on the screen. You will need to read up on the `Pen`, `Brush` and `Color` objects; they allow you to define the border, fill, and color of your circle. I would place the drawing logic in the control's `OnPaint()` method, which is called whenever the window is told to redraw itself. To have your object move at regular intervals, set up a `Timer` with some regular interval, and subscribe to its `Tick` event with a handler that will perform the moving logic. After you make each move, call `Invalidate()` on the control you have the Graphics handle for; that will cause the control to redraw itself. I would avoid getting the graphics handle for an entire form, or any control on which you place other nested controls, because a control that is repainting itself will also tell all its nested controls to repaint themselves. A `Panel` or `PictureBox` taking up a span in the form window is the go-to method for custom graphics. You may also consider implementing double-buffered graphics using a `BufferedGraphicsContext` object, or rolling your own by drawing your custom shapes on a `Bitmap` that you then set as the image for a `PictureBox`.

Answer (score 3):

Start with overriding OnPaint method on the Form and add draw logic there

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Color.Red), 0, 0, 100, 100);
}
```